# Is the space of finite point measures locally compact?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a polish locally compact space. If we define the space of finite point measures over $X$,
$$\mathcal{M}_p(X)=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{x_i}\left\vert\vphantom{\frac{1}{N}}\right.n\in\mathbb{N},x_i\in X\right\},$$
is this space locally compact under the topology of weak convergence? I'm having trouble trying to prove if it's true or not and i can't find a reference about this.

Any help will be appreciated.